# Phonegap window.open does not work on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I have an iOS/Android app built on cordova 2.6 and jqm 1.3. I need to open a link to an external website after the user clicks on a button. The code I am using is:

```
var ref = window.open('http://google.com','_self','location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart',function(event) {
    console.log('load started');
});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop',function(event) {    
    console.log('load stopped');
});
ref.addEventListener('loaderror',function(event) {
    console.log('load error = ' + JSON.stringify(event));
});
```

On iOS everything performs like I would expect. A new browser window opens with the google website loaded. But I cannot get anything to to load in Android. When I click on the button, nothing happens. I have put in console statements before and after the window.open, so I know the code is at least being executed.

My config.xml should be wide open for white listed sites:

```
<access origin=".*"/>;
```

I have tested on a Nexus 7 (android 4.2) and an android 2.2 emulator with the same results on both.

Does anyone know why window.open would not be firing correctly on android?

Comment: Do you have the InAppBrowser plugin listed in your config.xml file? Do you have the internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Both are in there. I just used the basic manifest created when you create a new phonegap project. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ` is in my manifest and `<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>` is in my config.xml

Comment: I just tried on my Nexus 7 (4.2) with the same setup and am not having a problem...however, I'm not using jqm...maybe this could be a problem? If you just launch that function with vanilla javascript, does it work? You did say that you were getting the console() messages though...nothing in the logs I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looked like it was a problem with 2.6 loading plugins on Android. I upgraded to 2.7 and everything started to work.

Comment: thanks for this. it was indeed a phonegap bug which wasted too much of my time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a solution to use the [ChildBrowser plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser)? This gives you a bit more control over the operation itself, while still preserving platform compatibility between iOS and Android.

In most cases, I use something like the following snippet to use the childbrowser to display an external page.

```
function openBrowser(url) {

    // determine if the childbrowser plugin is available
    var useChildBrowser = ('plugins' in window && window.plugins.childBrowser);

    if (useChildBrowser) {
        popup = window.plugins.childBrowser;
        popup.showWebPage(url, { showLocationBar: false, showAddress: false });
    } else {
        popup = window.open(url, 'Share', "['width=600px', 'height=400px', 'resizable=0', 'fullscreen=yes']"); 
    }
}
```

Note that this falls back to using `window.open` if the ChildBrowser plugin isn't available, so you won't break anything else with this. Could be worth a shot, perhaps?

Comment: I had actually messed with ChildBrowser for a few hours but ran into basically the same problem. That's when I realized that window.open was part of the 2.6 core functionality, so I decided to scrap ChildBrowser.